# How to hide Eject Button in Mac OS X for the permanent external drive like JetDrive

Tags: macos, mac, external-hard-drive, finder, eject

How can I hide the Eject Button for a certain external drive in the Mac OS X?

Because usually the external drive like JetDrive or StorEdge, does not need to be removed (I want to extend the disk space permanently).

But the Eject button is easier to be click. Then I have to pull the JetDrive out and push it back again carefully (it has a rather tiny handle).

Comment: Just in case it helps: I doubt it can be done. I have a Bitcasa Infinite Drive which cannot be ejected, but the icon still shows. When clicking it, OS X seems to eject it, but a second later [Bitcasa tells me not to do that](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GlQgC.png); I guess they would have hidden the eject button if doable. But maybe I'm wrong.